# RVM equivalent for PHP?

Tags: php, ruby, rvm, homebrew, rbenv

I can't seem to find a way to switch versions of PHP quickly. Is there something equivalent to ruby version manager for php? I need to switch between 5.3 and 5.2 on OS X.

Comment: A serious follow up question - I am just trying to install composer.. does composer manage php versions at all?

Comment: @DevinGRhode - No. You can set requirements for PHP versions using composer, but it can't manage them.

Answer (score 50):

For PHP alternatives to RVM and [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv), you have [phpbrew](https://github.com/c9s/phpbrew), [phpenv](https://github.com/CHH/phpenv) and [php-version](https://github.com/wilmoore/php-version). Please be aware that I am the author of php-version so of course I prefer it as I wrote it to scratch my own itch (I wanted something minimal with command completion); however, phpenv is quite good as well. You would do well to use either.

On OS X, you can install a PHP version manager using Homebrew.

First, add the PHP formulae for homebrew:

`% brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php`

Then, using the formulae installed from [homebrew-php](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php) you can install either with:

```
% brew install php-version
```

or

```
% brew install phpenv
```

The [php-version](https://github.com/wilmoore/php-version) [README.md](https://github.com/wilmoore/php-version#alternatives) lists a few more [alternatives](https://github.com/wilmoore/php-version#alternatives) so you might want to have a look.

BTW, I would consider `php-version` to be more aligned with [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) in that it tries to do one thing well.

Comment: Regarding php-fpm; yes, you should end up with a php-fpm binary for each PHP version you compile. When you use `php-version` or `phpenv` to switch versions, you will get the correct `php-fpm`. All they do is switch environment variables, including `$PATH` and `$MANPATH`.

Comment: This is very helpful for automated testing. Thanks!

Comment: php-version does not work form me. phpenv seem to be helpful. 
Thanks!

Comment: I found phpbrew doesn't offer a simple "brew install phpbrew" and so am going with php-version. I also ran `brew info phpbrew` and there was nothing. The readme+install docs for phpenv just don't mention any sort of "brew install". So I'm not sure that really works with phpenv anymore.

Comment: So if you are looking for a simple `brew install`.. it looks like php-version is indeed the way to go, despite phpbrew having much more github watchers+stars+forks

Comment: Not anymore, things have changed. `php-version` and `phpenv` are not even available in the `homebrew-php`, instead `phpbrew` is available, yet bugged as of now. I ended up installing my PHP versions from the tab directly and then I toggle them by updating the links. I.e. `brew link --overwrite --force shivammathur/php/php@8.0` to switch to 8.0. Clunky, but working.

Answer (score 10):

I think [phpfarm](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/Introducing%20phpfarm.htm) is most close php alternative of [rvm](https://rvm.io), it also installing [pyrus](http://pear2.php.net/) which is like ruby gems for php world.

Comment: phpfarm does not compile in my Mac, RVM is a serious thing phpfarm is not.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not use php-cgi and Install different versions of PHP to different locations

1. Find different version libphp5.so,and copy into the different location
2. If use php5.3.11 or php5.4.11

   ```
    ln -s php5.3.11 php  || ln -s php5.4.11
   ```
3. Depoly your apache httpd.conf

   ```
    LoadModule php5_module        YOUR_PHP_PATH/php/libphp5.so
   ```
4. restart apache

   ```
    sudo apachectl restart
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`phpenv`](https://github.com/chh/phpenv) (with [`php-build`](https://github.com/chh/php-build)). There's even a homebrew recipe if you `brew tap josegonzalez/php`. It's actually a PHP version of `rbenv` not `rvm` but I think it's going to be the simpler to set up than `phpfarm`.

Answer (score 0):

if you're running apache I can suggest the way I solved this.
Install different versions of PHP to different locations and prepare few apache php-x.y.z.conf files like

```
ScriptAlias /php/ "path/to/php-5.2.10/"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml
Action application/x-httpd-php "/php/php-cgi"
<Directory "/php/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

,

```
ScriptAlias /php/ "path/to/php-5.3.0/"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml
Action application/x-httpd-php "/php/php-cgi"
<Directory "/php/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and so on, so you can quickly change the name of included .conf file and restart server. Or, like I did, make several virtual hosts having the same document root, but with different versions of PHP included:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/localhost"
    ServerName local.php-5.2.10

    Include conf/php-5.2.10.conf

    <Directory "C:/www/localhost">
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It does not seem to affect command line in difference with rvm

Answer (score 0):

There is a great program for doing this, phpbrew. I actively use it and I can highly recommend it.

https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/wiki/Cookbook

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution ([pvers](https://github.com/zinovyev/pvers)). A one-file script written completely in bash. If you are looking for a lite and easy to install php version manager with minimum dependencies - give it a try;)